# Integrating custom fonts on React Native 0.71.2 giving sources.files.push

Tags: react-native

I got this error when try to link assets following this tutorial:

https://blog.devgenius.io/implement-custom-fonts-on-react-native-0-70-649c16f7609f

```
erich@Erichs-MacBook-Pro qvapay % npx react-native-asset
info Linking ttf assets to iOS project 
/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/react-native-asset/node_modules/xcode/lib/pbxProject.js:758
    sources.files.push(pbxBuildPhaseObj(file));
            ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'files')
    at pbxProject.addToPbxResourcesBuildPhase (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/react-native-asset/node_modules/xcode/lib/pbxProject.js:758:13)
    at pbxProject.addResourceFile (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/react-native-asset/node_modules/xcode/lib/pbxProject.js:264:14)
    at /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/react-native-asset/lib/copy-assets/ios.js:21:17
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at addResourceFile (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/react-native-asset/lib/copy-assets/ios.js:20:8)
    at linkAssetsIOS (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/react-native-asset/lib/copy-assets/ios.js:30:22)
    at /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/react-native-asset/lib/index.js:130:7
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/react-native-asset/lib/index.js:105:15
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)

Node.js v19.7.0
```

Comment: Do you want to use a custom font in react native?

Comment: Did you able to solve this issue? I am encountering the same thing.